# How to create a multi user chat app in android using asmack

Tags: android, asmack

I am trying to create an app in android which will share data among multiple users. After doing some search, I found XMPP will suit my requirement as it supports multi-user chat. I'm able to implement 1 - 1 chat. But not able to do multi-user chat. Can somebody please share some example code for MUC in android using aSmack lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [MUC docs](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html) on the Openfire community site? They provide plenty of example code.

Also in aSmack you need to init some static code/providers manually as in normal smack it reads these from an META-INF file which davlik vm does not utilise.

eg: call this when your activity/application first loads

```
 Class.forName(org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.class.getName(), true, ctx.getClassLoader());
```

from: [InitStaticCode.java](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/static-src/custom/org/jivesoftware/smackx/InitStaticCode.java)

Alternatively just call

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SmackAndroid asmk = SmackAndroid.init(context);
```

which will init all providers.

BTW what server are you using, it must also support MUC creation?

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your help. I was trying to use googletalk as the server.